# Does it require to use https protocol when using external login providers such as facebook, google, twitter?

Tags: facebook, twitter, authentication, google-plus

I have an MVC web application which uses **http** protocol and i have implemented external login providers (Facebook, Google, Twitter) to login users into the application.

At development phase of the application, i tried to login from external providers over http without any problem.

But i wonder if i publish the app into production environment, there will be a problem because i didn't use **https**?

Shortly, does it require to use https protocol when using external login providers such as facebook, google, twitter?

Comment: Apart from that you don’t _need_ it, you __should__ use HTTPS – after all, you are dealing with customer/member data on your site, and it is your responsibility to keep that as safe as possible. Letsencrypt makes it really easy nowadays to get a basic SSL cert for your domain; and if you can’t use that, other services like StartSSL provide basic certificates for free as well.

Comment: that's the response that i need. thank you. @CBroe

Answer (score 0):

You only need https for Facebook, and only if you create Page Apps or Canvas Apps. That being said, it´s a good idea to get a certificate anyway.

Comment: So you are saying that if i don't use https and get a certificate, users **cannot** login into my website with facebook, right?

Comment: what? no, of course that is NOT what i am saying...if you don´t know what page apps or canvas apps are, google it or take a look at the facebook docs...

Comment: when you create an app in facebook you should first choose a platform between ios, android, facebook canvas and website options. I have chosen website option for my application. So, you dont mean facebook page apps are the apps when you choose website option, right?

Comment: no, there is a specific platform for page apps (page tabs).